# Makefile won't be created

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, makefile

I am new to C++, and I am trying to do the following. I am using mac, have Xcode installed and am trying to create a makefile. I currently have the following files in my folder:

main.cpp

Foo.cpp

Foo.hpp

I step into the folder and try the command make. It gives me the following:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

I also tried "make main" which gave:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make: *** [main] Error 1

And some other stuff above that. I am new to the makefile and I am not sure how to create it. However, when I sent the files to my friend who has Ubuntu, he just typed in make and compiled it immediately, something I do not understand why I do not get.

Positive to all response and explanation to exactly how one procedures to create a makefile. It is supposed to be generated automatically, isn't it? Or do I have write it myself?

I tried to create a makefile, and follow an example, but it threw me an error talking about indents.

Thank you!

Comment: Please compare output of `make -v` on both system. I think on MacOSX you've another implementation of `make` (for example BSD make, not GNU make like on ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

You do not create a makefile by running `make`, just as you do not
create `Foo.cpp` by running the C++ compiler. You create a makefile
by writing it in an editor, just you as create `Foo.cpp`

So to create a makefile you need to learn how to write one, in the
language of `make`, to accomplish what you want it to, just as you
needed to learn C++ to write `Foo.cpp`.

Once you have written a makefile, you can run `make` to process that
makefile and carry out the tasks that you have coded in the makefile.
These will normally be tasks that automate the building of some
software you have written in such a way that (re)building it can
be done with minimum work in minimum time.

Different versions of `make` have broadly similar yet significantly different
languages. Find out what version of `make` you are using (`$ make -v`) and
then study its documentation and online tutorials about it. The language of `make` is
very much simpler than C++, but is still sufficiently complex that you
cannot learn it by guesswork.

The most widely used version is GNU Make. Here is [an introductory
tutorial](http://opensourceforu.com/2012/06/gnu-make-in-detail-for-beginners/).
For authoritative documentation, here is [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Answer (score 0):

[adding to what mike said..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43276580/5291005)

the `Makefile` is something completely independent of Xcode (Swift), which means either you cant create one/ use it urself unless you go deeeeeep into xcode build systems, the lldb compiler and targeting...(as far as compiling from Xcode.app)

[download this makefile on my github if you want to build c++ on mac](https://github.com/esphung/cPlusPlusTemplates/tree/master/oopTemplate)

i use it to start new c++ projects with a makefile that i have control over. use it to build your own in the future...its a simple barebones example of what we are discussing (for macOS)